# How to Auto-Select Only Window in Expose (OSX Lion)

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion, expose, keyboard-navigation

Exposé doesn't automatically set focus on any window when called.  Can this be changed?

Background:

Normally a Windows/Cygwin user, but I've migrated to Lion because it's desktop + multi-touch works better.  I've finally got a great multi-desktop setup:

- 4-finger swipe for changing desktops/mission control
- System Preferences > Mission Control > "When switching to an application, switch to a space with open windows for the application" is OFF
- `Command-space` to bring up Alfred to change the focused program
- `Command-N` to bring up a clean new window
- `Ctrl+Command+Space` to exposé on active program

This is quite good for creating isolated desktops so I can keep focused on a single task.  But sometimes, you only have one main window for a program (Skype, iCal, Mail).  When I need to switch to that window, I want to be able to switch to the program with Alfred, strike `Ctrl+Command+Space` to bring up Exposé, and hit `Enter` to switch to the only window that Exposé brings up (the only window for the program).  But that doesn't work, because Exposé doesn't set focus on a window until you select it with the arrow keys or the mouse.

Anybody know if this can be changed?